# How to include video in Visual Basic program

Tags: .net, vb.net, video

I'm writing an application VisualBasic.NET and I would like to know how to play video file which I have included to project.
It would be good if the video is vieweable  without an internet connection.

Comment: Visual Basic.NET or VB6?

Comment: I don't know
I'm doing it in Visual Studio Express 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a forms desktop application you can embed a media player control in your form like shown here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562852(v=vs.85).aspx

and put a trigger to play it if you want to start automatically, like Form.OnLoad or something like that.

Comment: But can I somehow import video to project resources so I can have only one compact file?